# How can I clear the php STDIN before a new input?

Tags: stdin, php

I have a nooby question about php-cli.

I'm using this :

```
define("STDIN", fopen('php://stdin','r'));
$input = "";
while($input == "") {
   echo "Please enter : ";
   $input = fread(STDIN, 80);
}
```

Problem is :

If I enter more than 80 characters, say 100, the 20 extras characters are added to the next one.

How can i "clear" the STDIN before each input ?

Comment: I guess there is no need to clear the `STDIN` before each `fread`, is it?

Comment: FYI, `STDIN` is already defined by default as `fopen('php://stdin','r')`. No need to open that again. http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: If a type more than 80 characters in one fread, say 100, the 20 extras caracters are added to the next one.

Comment: So just fread until there is no more to read. Then STDIN is "empty".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `length` argument of `fread()` to higher value (i.e. 1024, 2048, 10000) - it determines **max** lenght of data read by `fread()`. If you need just up to 80 characters, then check that after the read and shorten using `substr()` when needed. You do not need to open the input stream if you use `STDIN` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php)) which is recommended due to bugs in handling of `php://stdin` up to PHP 5.2.1 ([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)).

```
$input = "";
while($input == "") {
   echo "Please enter : ";
   $input = fread(STDIN, 10000);
}
```

Also bear in mind `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, `STDERR` are already defined system constants. You should not use these names for your own constants.

Comment: Thank you for thoses explainations.